# How to use fsnotify to listen to a file not created yet

Tags: go, go-fsnotify

I'd like to use fsnotify to listen to a file that's not created when started that listening. The fsnotify listening is expected to exit either when the watched file is being written and closed, or it times out for a specific period. I'm aware that we can use channel to set the timeout, but not sure how to achieve listening to a file that hasn't created yet.

I guessed we can listen to the directory containing this file (e.g. if the wanted file is `/tmp/temp.txt`, we can just listen to `/tmp/`), but not sure how to limit that listening to just that file (there could be other files under that dir changes during that listening and I don't want them to bother)

Comment: Wouldn't you simply listen to changes to the file's parent?

Comment: @JeffHolt Yes i guessed we can listen to the directory containing this file, but not sure how to limit that listening to just that file (there could be other files under that dir changes during that listening and I don't want them to bother)

Comment: The manner in which you listen would depend on the frequency of changes to the parent. If the frequency is too high, then you'd probably have to poll for the file's existence unless there's a *very* cheap interface that can execute each time the parent changes.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could do something like this

```
func checkFile(path string) {
    for {
        if _, err := os.Stat(path); errors.Is(err, os.ErrNotExist) {
            log.Println("File doesn't exist")
        } else {
            log.Println("File exists")
            // Start fsnotify here :)
            // Optionally break out of the loop, etc.
        }
        time.Sleep(time.Second * 1) // Can change this value if you see fit
    }
}

func main() {
    checkFile("./test")
}
```

That will log something like this

```
2021/12/15 18:51:00 File doesn't exist
2021/12/15 18:51:01 File doesn't exist
// I manually created a file called test
2021/12/15 18:51:07 File exists
2021/12/15 18:51:08 File exists
```

Answer (score 0):

At least the Linux kernel has [no inotify support](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/154004/can-inotify-be-used-to-watch-for-a-specific-file-to-be-created-without-monitorin) for a path that doesn't exist yet. Even the new [fanotify](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/fanotify.7.html) API doesn't support this.

Watching the directory is the only way to get notified about file creation in that directory.